# ある条件下での配列の存在チェックで最適な物はドレ?

Tags: php

早速本題なのですが
頭から詰められている(添え字の0から順に格納されている)配列を作成した場合、
`if(0<count($arr))`　or　`if(isset($arr[0]))`
どちらがいいでしょうか？
理由も添えて回答頂けると助かります。

この質問をするに至った経緯が日単位で数千～数万のアクセスが想定される環境があり、
"少しでも最適化したい。"となった際に意見が出たので……。
勿論、この他にもベストなチェックがあればご教授下さい。

追記：
秒間100PVほどアクセスがある可能性が有ります。
サーバースペックについてはお話しできませんが、それを想定されたスペックではあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本件の直接的な回答にはならないかもしれないので恐縮ですが、
面白いサイトがありましたのでここで紹介させていただきます。

My PHP Performance Benchmarks  
http://maettig.com/code/php/php-performance-benchmarks.php  
「Check if an Array is empty」というのがありますが、  
phpのバージョンが古い（version 5.2.17）ようです。

The PHP Benchmark
http://www.phpbench.com/  
こちらは「isSet() vs. empty() vs. is_array()」の比較がありました。

本家SOでは「count vs empty」でemptyを使用するがベストアンサーに選ばれていました。
※countの場合は配列のサイズでオーバヘッドが大きくなるっぽいことが書いてありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216110/checking-for-empty-arrays-count-vs-empty

「An empty array is equal to false in PHP - no need for empty() or count().」  
こんなコメントもついています。

蛇足ですが、「empty」と「isset」は挙動が異なるので注意が必要です。  
公式リファレンスによると「empty() は本質的に !isset($var) || $var == false と同じ」とのことです。  
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.empty.php

Comment: 本家の方までは見ていませんでしたが、ベンチマークまであるのですね参考になります。

Answer (score 2):

「頭から詰められている配列」の意味がよく分かりませんが…
配列が空でないことをチェックするなら`if(0<count($arr))`で良いと思います。

`if(isset($arr[0]))`だと、`$arr = [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'];`のような場合、真になりません。

Comment: 配列を作成後に添え字0~順に格納されると言う意味です。

Comment: なるほど… PHPの場合添え字が0から始まるとは限らないので、読み下しできませんでした、すみません。

Answer (score 1):

配列の添え字が必ず 0 から始まるような状況であれば、どちらでもいいと思います。

前後のコードがありませんので推測でしかありませんが、そもそもこの配列ですら動的に作っているのでしたら以下のコードをお勧めします。

`if( is_array($arr) && !empty($arr) )`

理由は、添え字が 0 から始まらない場合でも配列であることが保障できますし、中身が空ではないことも保障できます。

日に数千～数万というのは、PV の話でしょうか。それとも DAU でしょうか？

PV としてお話しますが、サーバスペックが掲載されていませんので具体的な話はできませんが
日に 50000 PV だとしても、ピーク時間で多く見積もっても 1 時間あたり 10000 人に届かないぐらいですよね。
秒間 3 人ほどの閲覧であれば、何の支障にもならないと思いますし、こういった細かいところを最適化する意味はないと思います。

Comment: 波はありますが秒間100に行くことがあるんです。補足で追加させていただきます。

Comment: サーバの負荷状況をこちらで把握することができませんので具体的な言及は避けさせていただきます。 xdebug 等を使って最適化すると、より効果的な最適化ができると思います。http://blog.howtelevision.co.jp/entry/2014/11/14/192350